# CoreText alternatives to deprecated CGContext text functions

Tags: ios, ios7, core-graphics, core-text

In iOS 7, several of the CGContext text drawing functions were deprecated in favor of Core Text:

[Deprecated CGContext Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html)

Sometimes Apple suggests specific alternatives to deprecated functions (e.g. "use x instead") but in this case, "x" is simply "Core Text", which isn't all that specific.

So, if I'm just in `-drawRect:` and I've got my `CGContextRef` and I'm ready to call `CGContextShowGlyphsAtPoint()`, what do I do instead? What's the best practice, and what's the simplest Core Text replacement that doesn't require refactoring any drawing code beyond that call (if such a thing exists)?

Bonus points for an answer that concisely answers this for each of the deprecated text functions on that page—I'm most interested in `CGContextShowGlyphsAtPoint()`, but this could serve as a good reference for others seeking alternatives to any of those functions.

Comment: You may give `CTFontDrawGlyphs` a try. You'll probably have to do some calculations, but this seems the best method that I've seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the intention is for `CGContextShowGlyphsAtPoint` to be replaced by [CGContextShowGlyphsAtPositions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextShowGlyphsAtPositions).  You can get the glyph positions with `CTRunGetPositionsPtr` or (if that returns `NULL`), `CTRunGetPositions`.

AFAICT, `CGContextShowGlyphsAtPositions` also replaces several other former CoreText functions, such as `CGContextShowGlyphs`, `CGContextShowText`, and `CGContextShowTextAtPoint`.  Other former CoreText functions like `CGContextSelectFont` are replaced by multiple new functions (in that case, `CGContextSetFont` and `CGContextSetFontSize`).  I believe this is all fairly self-explanatory by reading [the API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextShowText).

There may be other deprecated functions I didn't specifically mention, but I figure you get the point.